# I want to change the name of r and theta in Plotly (R Software)

Tags: r, plotly, data-science

I need some help in Plotly, i want to change the name of r and theta in scatterpolar, and i don't know how [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9zvX.png)

Here is the code :

````
fig <- plot_ly(
  type = 'scatterpolar',
  color = I("purple"),
  r = radar$CAeuro,
  theta = radar$Mois,
  name="Chiffre d'affaires mensuel en Euros",
  fill = 'toself'
);fig```

Thanks a lot
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `hovertemplate` to your code.
Here an example for you (with some arbitrary data since I don't have yours):

```
plot_ly(
  type = 'scatterpolar',
  color = I("purple"),
  r = iris$Sepal.Length,
  theta = iris$Sepal.Width,
  name="Chiffre d'affaires mensuel en Euros",
  hovertemplate = paste('<i>New R</i>: %{r}',
                        '<br><b>New Theta</b>: %{theta}<br>'),
  fill = 'toself'
)
```

[image]